# Is initializing a new socket in every method a good thing?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asyncsocket

So I'm trying to tackle sockets programming in C# .NET, but there are no good articles/guides about it from what I've seen and found (even the official MSDN site has outdated code in there). I'm trying to follow this link [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f(v=vs.100).aspx), but since it's quite out-dated, I'm unsure if the code included in there is considered good practice.
And so, there's this code:

```
public void StartListening() {
    Socket listener = new Socket( localEP.Address.AddressFamily,
    SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp );

    listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(acceptCallback), listener);
}
```

And then there is this code:

```
public void acceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) {
    Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
}
```

Why does the `acceptCallback` initialize a new socket? Why do all the methods initialize a socket of their own? Wouldn't it be better to justhave one, class-wide private socket like this

`private Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);`? And why does it first create a listener socket and then a handler socket? What's the point to that? Also, what happens to the listener passed as an argument in the `BeginAccept` method? From the looks of it, it just goes and dies in a black hole.

And lastly, I'd be very grateful for any and all links to tutorials/articles which could help me understand socket programming.

Comment: Try sample code on following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex(v=vs.110).aspx.  The samples use Sockets, but you can use any TCP class (like TCPListener, TCPClient) which inherit the socket class.  I don't like initializing every method.  It is unnecessary, but some of Microsoft library methods don't work correctly if you don't open a new connection for each message.  The sample code you posted creates a STATE object and pass the same STATE object to each event (call-backs) so the code isn't opening and closing connections.  The STATE object is a passed argument.

Comment: I do have read earlier the link you've provided, I didn't include it in my post because it's just a raw version of the link I had posted above.
You expressed it in a confusing way (since I talked about initializing sockets, not methods), but are you saying that I need to open a new socket for every single message every time I want to send it?
And did I understood it right that this STATE object you're talking about is converted into `IAsyncResult` and passed as an argument to the callback method?

Comment: In most cases you do not need to open new socket for each connection.  You just have to be careful that some library methods automatically close the connection, and Microsoft made it very difficult to detect when connections open and close without using methods that actual do close the connection.  IAsyncResults.AsyncState is the state object.  See examples at the website I previously posted.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does the acceptCallback initialize a new socket?

This is how the BSD derived socket APIs work (and reflects how the TCP/IP network stack works).

You create a first socket whose sole job is to wait for incoming connections: via the `Listen` (or variant) method and then establish the connection via `Accept` method (or variant).

Which returns another `Socket` instance that will be used for communicate with one client<sup>1</sup> socket.

The initial listening socket continues to be available for new incoming connections.

This reflects the model of a server with many clients connecting to it.

One can think of `Socket` being overloaded with two functions: 1. listing for and accepting connections, 2. representing an established connection.

Stack Overflow does not generally do recommendations (they tend to become out of date too quickly): I learnt this when Sun systems ran Sun OS writing in C at the end of the 80s so I'm in no position to recommend anything anyway :-).

---

<sup>1</sup> Once a connection is established operations between client and server are – at the socket level – symmetric, but it is useful to think about server & client roles when thinking about establishing connections.

Comment: So I need a socket for listening for new clients and additional sockets for every client I want to receive data from and send data to (1 for each client)?

Comment: @Amai Yes. n+1 sockets for n clients.